# SQL - LIKE search in address fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, full-text-search

I have SQL query, which searchs in table with address fields. My problem is in City field. 
I assumed search column streets with house number and without him but I forgot the division of neighborhoods like: Kolin IV, Kolín II, etc. My question is, can somehow from the column using the SQL function to compare only the name of the city without any indication to which the district belongs?

```
$where = " WHERE (LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%')
 OR LOWER(street) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%')
 OR CAST(postal_code AS TEXT) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%')
 OR CAST(house_number AS TEXT) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%')
 OR (LOWER(street || ', ' || city) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%'))
 OR (LOWER(street || ' ' || CAST(house_number AS TEXT)) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%'))
 OR (LOWER(city || ' ' || CAST(postal_code AS TEXT)) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%'))
 OR (LOWER(street || ', ' || city || ' ' || CAST(postal_code AS TEXT)) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%'))
 OR (LOWER(street || ' ' || CAST(house_number AS TEXT) || ', ' || city) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%'))
 OR (LOWER(street || ' ' || CAST(house_number AS TEXT) || ', ' || city || ' ' || CAST(postal_code AS TEXT)) LIKE LOWER('%$fullAddress%'))) AND deleteby is null";
$results = $fce->_slctSQL("public.configurations_view", "", "services", $where, "", " ORDER BY city ASC, street ASC, house_number ASC, postal_code ASC", "");
```

Comment: BTW: when i compared: 

Vrchlické 789, Kolín IV 28002 - its OK
Vrchlické 789, Kolín 28002 - its FAIL

Comment: Comparing everything to the full address seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that this works:

```
 OR (LOWER(city || ' ' || CAST(postal_code AS TEXT)) LIKE LOWER(REPLACE('%$fullAddress%', ' ', '%'))
```

However, this could introduce other issues, if cities have multi-word names.